# Custom Object Section in Account is not Showing Custom Fields

Tags: community, custom-object, custom-field, sandbox

I have Created an Custom Object "Text Subscriptions" And also created a Custom Fields as Account which has Master-details Field type. I have Created some More Custom fields: Text Plan, SMS Number, status, Renewal Date. 
I am able to add data into these custom Objects but when it is displayed as a section in Account layout it only shows the Standard Field of My Custom Object: Text Subscription Name(Standard Object). Please check the below image

[image]

Now My concern is, how can i display the rest of Custom fields along with Text Subscription Name in different columns.
Let me make myself clear that this is a sandbox.

Image of Account Page Layout:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit the Account layout and goto Text Subscription related list. Click on setting icon at the right corner of the related list and add the field which you need

Comment: @wAitIngdOg I have already added the required custom fields in related List but still nothing is happening...

Comment: Check whether you have the permissions for those fields. Go to that field setup and check Visibility. 

Did you deploy these fields in your sandbox or created it manually?

Comment: I created all the fields manually..and checked the visibilty

Comment: Can you post the Screenshot of the related list pagelayout where you have added the fields

Comment: @wAitIngdOg i have edited my question and added the screen shot.

Comment: Then when you save the layout, it is not visible?

Comment: Yes @wAitIngdOg, when i save it and go back to Account detail page its only Shows my Text Subscription Name, not other fields which i added in layout

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible reasons,

1. Fields not added in the layout

   ***Edit the Account layout and goto Text Subscription related list. Click on setting icon at the right corner of the related list and add the field which you need***
2. Field level permission not given

   ***Goto Field setup , check the visibility***

Comment: Thanks wAitIng dOg for your Support, but i managed to get it visible somehow. I opened an Individual account and then Click on "Edit Layout". After this i added the required fields into related List and it worked. I don't know why it was not working on the other way. Anyways Thanks!!

Comment: You might have multiple Account Page layouts. Check whether you are editing the right layout or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the required fields in the related list layout.

**Go to required page layout of 'Account' object, click on edit, search of related list section, click on wrench icon for 'Text Subscriptions', add the required fields in the layout.**

Refer the screenshot below.

[image]

Let me know if this doenst work.

Comment: I have already done these steps but still no change appear. I have given the permissions also. Is there anything else i might be missing??